# Getting newly inserted contacts in Android

Tags: java, android, database, service, contacts

In my application, I'm extracting all the contacts and upload them to the server. But there's a problem. I know how to extract all the contacts, but is there any way to get the newest contacts?

For example: The first time I open the app, I upload all the contacts but the other times I don't want to upload all of them, just the newest.

Do you know any way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: can u provide the code same thing iam trying but iam not geeting please halp me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your contacts have some order (by ID, by Name), you can save the identifier of the last contact you saved and the next time just check to see if there is a contact with identifier bigger than the last one you saved.

For example:

1. You save a list of contacts and the last saved contact ID (assuming they are ordered, if not then save the max) was 100.
2. Next run, you check to see if you have any contact with ID > 100 and you save these, and again you save the last inserted ID.

Comment: Will be useful also to implements the ContentObserver when something is changed on the contacts table and get it easily?

Comment: ftom2 can u please provide the code,iam also doing same thing but iam not geeting

Comment: @shassss - please open a question and post some code so we can try to help.

Comment: @ftom2 The first time I open the app, I upload all the contacts but the other times I don't want to upload all of them,New contacts have to save,dont want reputition the same contacts