# Sync only newly inserted Contact in Phonebook in an android app

Tags: android

Is it possible to Sync only newly inserted Contact in Phonebook in an android app ? Suppose I hv sync my Phonebook with an app for first time and save these Contacts. Again when I need to display those Contacts then only the newly inserted Contacts will be sync and others are only retrieve from database.

Comment: I think this link will help you and you can solve your problem : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11281244/7806873

Comment: No actully this won't help me Because if i deleted any of contact then it won't remove that contact from the app. but yes we can update new inserted contacts. But I want accurate sync :)

Comment: well, Thanx for giving hint.

Comment: I hope these two links will guide you more : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37925202/syncing-contacts-using-syncadapter-working  and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41988836/delete-contact-from-android-contacts

Comment: thanks it works :)

Comment: Great!!! If you don't mind add answer here or send me for future needs.

Comment: sure, i did it with ContentObserver and service with background

Comment: give me ur email id code is more than 1200 chars n not allowed here to post :|

Comment: Did you try as answer?

Comment: no i tried as a comment

Comment: Insert as `Your Answer` section at bellow comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        public class ContactListenerService extends Service {
            MyContentObserver contentObserver = new MyContentObserver();
            @Nullable
            @Override
            public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate() {
                super.onCreate();

                getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, true, contentObserver);
            }

            @Override
            public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            boolean flag = PreferencesManager.getInstance(this).optBoolean("flag");
                if(flag==false){
                    Toast.makeText(this, flag+"  val", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    PreferencesManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).putBoolean("flag",false);
                    // your method to sync contact
                }
                return  Service.START_STICKY;
            } 
        private class MyContentObserver extends ContentObserver {

                boolean flag=false;

                public MyContentObserver() {
                    super(null);
                }

                @Override
                public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
                    PreferencesManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).putBoolean("flag",true);
                    super.onChange(selfChange);
                }

                @Override
                public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
                    return super.deliverSelfNotifications();
                }
            }


        }
        public class ContactSyncScreen extends BaseFragment {
         @Override
        public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Your other stuff 
            //Start the service form fragment
            Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),ContactListenerService.class);
            getActivity().startService(intent);
    }
  }
```